# How can I share `c:\program files`?

Tags: windows, samba, smb, cifs

actually, it is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`. I want to store my vim configs into this folder and broadcast it on lan. I've given Everyone read access and Administrator read/write/delete(or whatever that 3 permissions were) access. currently it is on share list and I can see this from thunar file manager but I can't mount this folder. It says I have no permission - even though I'm logging in with Administrator credentials. How can I share this folder?

Comment: Old now, but file share permissions are separate from the permissions on the file system. Did you just assign these permissions to the file system, or  just on the file share?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Vista moving forward - there are special permissions set on C:\Program Files\ and c:\Program Files (x86)\ and they are considered system folders.   I suggest installing VIM in C:\VIM\ and then share your vim configs dir from there.  I bet you wont have any issues :)

For an example of what I am talking about, go into any of your program files directories and find a text file somewhere.  Open that text file in notepad, add a space, save the file.  Even though you opened the file, and have administrator rights over the machine - you can't just write directly to a file in Program Files - even a text file.

Comment: did this answer your question?   if so please mark it as such.